# Mark a method as deprecated

Tags: ios, xcode, api

I have a change in my API and I want to mark one method as deprecated. 
I've put the following on it's signature:
     **attribute**((deprecated("Don't use this method")));
However, I don't know how do I need to behave in the method body itself.

Can't find anything on Apple coding starts to lead me. 
The method return BOOL. 
should I just return false?

Comment: Why are you marking it as deprecated?

Comment: How i mark a method as deprecated:
-(void)method __attribute__((deprecated)); (.h)
-(void)method __attribute__((deprecated)){}(.m)

That always works for me.

Comment: Because it's a method that takes 2 parameters and in the new version I made a new function that get an array. 
So basically they behave the same - just passing the parameters to the array.
The only difference is that this method is with pointers to the NSMutualStrings and the array I'm getting is an array of strings.

Comment: @iOSAddicted it's not my question. My deprecation works but what is the approach I should assimilate in the method body itself?

Comment: Deprecated means that the method should still work, but it isn't recommend you call it as there is a new approach that should be adopted.

Comment: I suggest not to use this method at all!

Comment: @aniket I don't want anyone to use it. that's the point of deprecation isn't it?

Comment: No if you don't want anyone to use it, delete it. Deprecated means it will be removed in the future and it isn't recommended you use it anymore. BUT it should still work if called.

Comment: Jeff is right. Even if it is a deprecated method, it should still work. If you don't want anyone to use it, then delete it from the API

Comment: Omit it from the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deprecated means the method still work, but can be removed in the future versions and the new method is most preferred.

You can give some additional info to the user who uses the deprecated method:

```
/**
 * @deprecated This method is deprecated starting in version x.x
 * @note Please use @code newMethod:withNewParameter: @endcode instead.
 */
-(void)depFunction:(id)x __attribute__((deprecated));
```

When he use like:

```
[yourClassObj depFunction:@"argument"];
```

The Quick Help Panel will show an information like:

[image: Deprecated]

You might also want to change `attribute((deprecated("Don't use this method")));` to `DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Don't use this method, use the other one instead.");`